# How can you remove staff from Google Analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics

I see my staff has implemented Google Analytics in their app but I am pretty sure there is a significant amount of traffic that is coming from them testing the tool in production.

How can I make sure that they aren't adding to the analytics so we only see customer data? Is it setting or do i need to get them all to install a GA blocking extension in chrome? The latter sounds a little hacky.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filter to exclude the traffic from the staff members.

You could use their IP addresses to exclude them: [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for this but how does this work with remote teams who would all have different IP's. I am guessing every will need to install something like Ghostery and remove code as needed.